# Do something when using mouse wheel over tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to have some code executed, when I use the mouse wheel over the tab bar?

I have been searching the Google Chrome API documentation for that but haven't found anything so far. I want to add that I haven't created an extension yet, but I have an idea for one.

Comment: No, such an API does not exist. Why do you need such an API?

Comment: I was looking for an extension to be able to switch tabs by using the mouse wheel. That's the one last thing I that keeps me at firefox.

I haven't found an extension yet, so I figured it's not possible, but I needed to ask to be sure.

Comment: If I scroll while holding my mouse over the tab strip, Chromium switches my tabs. You don't need an extension for this built-in feature.

Comment: @RobW that feature is built-in on Linux only. It was implemented for windows in the Chrome Toolbox extension using NPAPI, but it doesn't work anymore. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1316

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** tested but it contains all of the tools you need to accomplish an approximation of what you're asking.

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);

  function MouseWheelHandler(e){
    var TabPosBarOnYAxis = 100;
    var wheelUp = (e.wheelDeltaY > 0) ? true : false;
    if(e.pageY < (TabPosBarOnYAxis + 50) || e.pageY > (TabPosBarOnYAxis - 50)){
      if(wheelUp)  
       //Do something like change the active tab, or alert something, or whatever
      else
        //Do something else
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**
After testing this, it does not work. The event listener only listens as long as the mouse is over the `document` object. I tried attaching to the `window` as well and no go.